# Can applications read Win + V clipboard history?

Tags: windows-10, security, clipboard

Are Windows applications generally able to read everything copied into Win + V clipboard (with "save multiple items" enabled in settings) without any user interaction or escalated permission, just like they can with the regular clipboard?

[image: Win + V clipboard, from https://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2018/05/11/windows-10s-new-clipboard-takes-the-pain-out-of-copy-and-pasting/]

Comment: That interface uses the **history** of items placed onto the clipboard, so any program could easily monitor as items are put in the clipboard and create their own history independently from this dialog. I do not know if they can directly access that interface, but there's absolutely nothing stopping them from mimicing it, there are already many clipboard history programs that already do this.

Comment: Applications must be able to read and write to your clipboard.  Doesn’t mean they have to support the clipboard function.